# python for loop extending

Tags: python

I wonder why the for loop is not extending it's iteration:

```
    for link in frontLinks:  
        #try:           
        getCurlink = self.getHref(link) # get current site links
        #print getCurlink
        #print frontLinks 
        if getCurlink:
            frontLinks = frontLinks + getCurlink
```

This line:

```
frontLinks = frontLinks + getCurlink
```

doesn't apply to frontLinks of the "for" loop. Any ideas??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The for loop evaluates its expression once, to get an iterator.  Later, you re-bind the name `frontLinks` to be a new list.  The new list won't have anything to do with the for loop.

Although it is tricky to modify a list while iterating over it, it's OK to add to the end of the list, it will work.  Change your last line to this:

```
frontLinks.extend(getCurlink)
```

Comment: i am using list so it is extend.

Comment: @Dubslow: This can be inferred from badc0re's code - both parameters need to be lists in `frontlinks + getcurlink`.

Comment: @Tim That is true, but one could also argue that `self.getHref` implies it returns an href (ie, a string)... but yeah, 6 of one, half dozen t'other (But will admit to not having noticed the comment that says 'links' - so mea culpa)

Comment: @TimPietzcker Sorry, my bad, I made a stupid. I'd never seen extend() before :)

Answer (score 1):

You will not see changes in a list while iterating over it.

You need to use something like:

```
 while i < len(frontLinks):
     link = frontLinks[i]
     ...
     if condition:
       frontLinks.append(item)
     i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can append to a list while iterating, I would use one list and a deque (you can use a list instead of deque, just replace `todo.popleft()` with `todo.pop(0)`):

```
from collections import deque

done = []
todo = deque(frontLinks) # your initial frontLinks
while todo:
    link = todo.popleft() # take the first element from todo
    getCurlink = self.getHref(link) # get current site links
    if getCurlink:
        todo.extend(getCurlink) # extend the todo list
    done.append(link)
```

This way you always have two collections with clear roles: `todo` and `done`. You can stop/resume the iteration, dump/load the current state, etc. without having to restart the whole process.