# Adding elements to a list that is iterating and iterates through the new elements using the same for loop for Python

Tags: python

I know I can append elements in a list, run a for loop going through that list and add more elements in it. But I'm wondering if I can add more elements in the list and have the same for loop iterate through the new elements added as well, rather than making a new for loop to iterate through the new elements.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Anthony. If you could post an example of the output you would like, and even of these for loops you've mentioned, it'd make your question easier to answer. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python for loop extending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412132/python-for-loop-extending)

Comment: Sorry MJM, I'm kind of new to posting question. I'll make sure to do that next time! and Thank you mkrieger1, that link you sent gave me an idea of how I can do this.

Comment: You don't have to wait for the next time, you can edit your post and include sample code.

Comment: No need to apologise, just a general tip when you're asking a question. I hope the answers below have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use while instead of for loop

```
i=0
mylist = [1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 15]
while i < len(mylist):
    currentValue = mylist[i]
    if currentValue == 2:
        mylist.append(21)  # append something
    print(currentValue)
    i += 1
```

the output will be

```
1
2
5
7
8
15
21
```

Comment: thankk you this might work as well!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but I would not recommend it unless you know exactly what you are doing. Here are two ways:

```
a = [0]
for i in a:
    if len(a) < 10:
        a.append(i+1)

print(a)

a = [0]
i = 0
while len(a) < 10:
    a.append(i+1)
    i += 1

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this. A simple example:

```py
counter = 5
arr = [1,2,3]

for item in arr:
  if counter > 0:
    counter -= 1
    arr.append("x")

  print(item)


1
2
3
x
x
x
x
x
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special to do, just append to the list within the loop:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
for v in a:
    print(v)
    if v<4: a.append(v+4)

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

*be careful not to create infinite loops though*